# Create server control like panel and linklabel using javascript

Tags: javascript, servercontrol

I want to add panel control using javascript inside the TD element.

Is it possible to create these control using **Document.createElement** and **appendChild**

methods?

I also want to show and hide this panel control **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [div](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DIV.asp) element for panel.

You can use [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp) element for linklabel.

Actually asp.net panel is rendered as div and linkbutton rendered as anchor.

You can use the [display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530751%28VS.85%29.aspx) property to show and hide panel.

set display to none hides the div

set display to block or inline shows the div.

Comment: i try with div element but after make it hidden,a space is still present there. Is there any way to remove empty space?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit off-track, but I would recommend having a look at JQuery which makes javascript'ing more intuitive